# Automation Array Formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I need to make a formula that generates the number of the incident in this data

Whenever someone takes an action from consequences tab I should choose the incident and the number of it so if someone took the same incident before and will take it again this will be the 2nd time with a different action and every action has a 180 days expiry which is represented in the expiry column 0 means expired 1 means, not expired

what I need here is to generate the number of incidents automatically when the array formula looks at the name of the employee then it counts the incident if the incident number is equal 2 then it means 2 times same incident so generate 2nd time and if it is equal 3 it means 3 times same incident ETC...

I have tried this array but it counts all the errors without taking the agent as criteria

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Number of incidents (Automation)",IF(LEN(A:A)=0,IFERROR(1/0),IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B:B)=0," ",IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)=6,"6th Time",IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)=5,"5th Time",IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)=4,"4th Time",IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)=3,"3rd Time",IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)=2,"2nd Time",IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)=1,"1st Time"," "))))))))))
```

here is a sample of the data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OqxTwyeZlbzYsUYIF6sNqkQS3uzEkpyC15RRVP2P4rA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this in **D1**:

```
={"Number of incidents (Automation)"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C), COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C)), ))}
```

[image: 0]

---

if that needs to be per employee then use:

```
={"Number of incidents (Automation)"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C), COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C, B2:B&C2:C, ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C)), ))}
```

---

and to exclude expired you can do:

```
={"Number of incidents (Automation)"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F=1, COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C&F2:F, B2:B&C2:C&F2:F, ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C)), ))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the tremendous support player0, I need to add criteria for each employee, for example, Jacob has 2 incidents Adherence to Breaks the first time he will take action from consequences but the second time he will take a different action, so I need the equation to count the incidents for every employee to be able to determine the action that he will receive, noting that I have to keep in mind that if the first incident for Jacob was from 180 days ago it will expire so the second incident will be considered as the first incident as the first one already expired

Comment: thank you so much it worked, may I ask if it is possible so that I can add the expiry column to be in the equation if the expiry is =0 so the action is expired so it wouldn't count?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you exactly want. But hope this helps you.

Instead of

> IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)=X,"Xnd Time"

You can write

> IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)&"nd Time"

in full formula

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Number of incidents (Automation)",IF(LEN(A:A)=0,IFERROR(1/0),IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B:B)=0," ",COUNTIF(C:C,C:C)&"th Time"))))

Comment: Thank you for your response / what I need here is to count the number of the incident, For example, Jacob has 2 incidents Adherence to Breaks the first time he will take action from consequences but the second time he will take a different action so I need the equation to count the incidents for every employee to be able to determine the action noting that I have to keep in mind that if the first incident for Jacob was from 180 days it will expire so the second incident then will be the first incident as the first one already expired